# Encode event results as colors

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I want to reduce time complexity of my code that solves the following problem.

> The program receives a positive distance d followed by a sequence of n
> events: An event can be either that a person appeared at some position, or that a person disappeared
> from some position. After each event, your program should output
> "red" if there are currently at least two persons at distance exactly
> d, and "yellow" otherwise. Note that initially (before the first
> event) all positions are empty. The events are given as a 2D array
> `event[0..n-1][0..1]`, where `event[i][0]` is "1" if a person appeared at position `event[i][1]` (on the x-axis), and
> "-1" if a person disappeared from that position. The output is an
> array `light[0..n-1]` of strings, where `light[i]` is the color directly
> after `event[i]`.

I used the following code to solve this problem.

```
def cal_dis(d,pairs):
    found = False
    for i in range(0, len(pairs)-1):
        if(pairs[i+1]- pairs[i]) == d:
            found = True
            break
    return "red" if found else "yellow"

def tracker(n,d,event):
    ret = [""] * n
    pairs = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        if event[i][0] == 1:
            pairs.append(event[i][1])
            ret[i]= cal_dis(d,sorted(pairs))
        else:
            pairs.remove(event[i][1])
            ret[i]= cal_dis(d,sorted(pairs))
    return ret
```

### Sample Input

> first row: n d
>
> next n rows: two integers; the first one is either -1
> or 1, the second one is nonnegative (these n rows correspond to the
> array "event")

```
7 4
1 2
1 10
1 6
-1 2
-1 6
1 9
1 14
```

### Sample Output

> n rows each consisting of either the string "red" or "yellow".

```
yellow
yellow
red
red
yellow
yellow
red
```

Comment: In one place the input is called a two-dimensional array, and later it seems to be a file-like. Are the input and output stdin/stdout, or actually in-memory lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a faster algorithm, update a count of neighboring pairs at distance D as you go.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def num_at_distance(d, pairs):
    # Keep track of whether each position is occupied or not.
    # Accepts a distance and a number of positions to update. Each position is a 2-tuple of:
    #   - -1 for not-occupied or 1 for occupied
    #   - A position which changed.
    # Returns [yellow, yellow, red...] as a generator

    # 'occupied' maps a position to whether it's occupied.
    # Everything is unoccupied to start (False).
    # For slightly faster performance you could switch to an array.
    occupied = defaultdict(bool)
    num_at_distance_d = 0
    for now_occupied, position in pairs:
        # A is the position D to the left of the update
        # i is the updated position
        # B is the position D to the right of the update
        a, i, b = position-d, position, position+d
        now_occupied = bool(now_occupied==1)

        if occupied[i] != now_occupied:
            occupied[i] = now_occupied
            if occupied[i]:
                # Use the fact that python's True and False are 1 and 0 for some math
                num_at_distance_d += occupied[a] + occupied[b]
            else:
                num_at_distance_d -= occupied[a] + occupied[b]
        if num_at_distance_d == 0:
            yield "yellow"
        else:
            yield "red"

if __name__=='__main__':
    input = 4, [(1,2), (1,10), (1,6), (-1, 2), (-1, 6), (1, 9), (1,4)]
    output = list(num_at_distance(*input))
    print(output)
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

#### Use understandable names

`cal_dis`? Do you mean `calculate_distance`? But it doesn't calculate. Maybe `find_at_distance` or just `find_distance` will be better? And `d` is also too short (but if all the project is these two functions, it may ok). Maybe `dist` could be better? And `event` is a list, not a single event. Should it be called `events`? And `pairs` are `positions`, right?

#### Some simplifications

In `cal_dis` - when you find the element at distance `d`, you don't need to break the loop - you just need to return "red", and return "yellow" after the loop. Drop the `found` flag.

More Pythonic way to write this is something like

```
return "red" if any(b - a == d for a, b in zip(pairs, pairs[1:])) else "yellow"
```

but I'm not sure it's more readable, especially for beginners.

In `tracker` - you don't need to create `ret` full of empty values, you can append elements unto it. The last line of both `if-else` branches is the same, so you can move if out of `if-else`:

```
if event[i][0] == 1:
    pairs.append(...)
else:
    pairs.remove(...)
ret.append(d, sorted(pairs))
```

Now, do we need `i`? It is used only to address elements of `event` list, so we can iterate this list:

```
for action, position in events:
    if action==1:
        pairs.append(position)
...
```

All together:

```
def find_distance(dist, positions):
    positions = sorted(positions)
    for i in range(len(positions) - 1):
        if positions[i+1] - positions[i] == d:
            return "red"
    return "yellow"

def tracker(_, dist, events): #first argument is excessive, we have len(events)
    result = []
    positions = []
    for action, position in events:
        if action == 1:
            positions.append(position)
        else:
            positions.remove(position)
        result.append(find_distance(dist, positions))
    return result
```

#### Better algorithm ideas

- you can track current state. If there was a removal, the result can't switch from "yellow" to "red", and if data was added, "red" can't switch to "yellow".
- if all positions are unique, you may keep them in a `set` instead of `list`, if they are not - use `collections.Counter`. This way you'll avoid sorting the `positions` every event, and checking if addition switched to "red" will be done in one check:

  `if (position - dist) in positions or (position + dist) in positions:`
- to efficiently check if the removal switches state to "yellow" you should keep track on every existing pair with distance `dist` in the `set` of pairs. Doing this for non-unique positions (with Counter) will be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is an algorithms practice question, and I don't think you want a review of your code. You just want the answer. Since this is doubtless from a practice site, why not just read the sample answers there?

That said, here is a hint on the answer: COUNT the number of pairs of people at distance exactly d as you go.

Whenever you update whether a person is at a particular location, check to the left d places, and to the right d places. If it helps, you can pad the array with d empty places to the left and right when you start.

This reduces the running time to linear, instead of quadratic.

Comment: can you point me to the practice website that you're talking about?

Comment: Where did you get this problem? That's the website I mean.

Comment: I didn't get it on a website for God's sake. A friend sent it to me to help him solve it. I was able write the code in a few minutes but I ran out of ideas to optimize it. If you know a website that has this question, then I can just see the sample solution and that's it. Why would someone post it here if they already could see the solution on a website?

Comment: Code review is /filled/ with competitive coders "why is my code too slow for this competitive algorithms question from a site". That, together with the highly unnatural nature of this problem, made me think you got it from a site. Now I think your friend got it from a site or as an interview question. If this is a just a problem one of you ran into, great job on writing it up in a very clear way!

Comment: Thanks for understanding

Comment: @PsyLogic Where did your friend get it from?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode he said he found the question on Fiver. He's a freelancer